# Geoprocessing Ungroups Layers in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing, layers, group-layer

Is there a fix for this, am I only imagining this, or is it a bug:

ArcMAP 10.1 for Desktop Build 3035 on a 64 bit Windows 7 system

When I run a geoprocessing task that modifies the input data (such as [Snap](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001v00000007000000)), if the input layer is in a group, the group is removed once the process is complete! I have lost groups with detailed definition queries to this problem.

I suppose removing the layer from the group before processing will help alleviate this. However, is there a more definite fix? I can easily see myself forgetting to separate that layer and subsequently losing my group.

Plus, there is no 'save map every x minutes' feature (that I know of), so closing without saving will bring back the groups, but will negate any changes I made while working.

Comment: I just tried this and I'm not having the same problem, maybe it's because of your definition query? Are you running the tool in the foreground?

Comment: Are you running the tool in the background? Unfortunately this is/was a bug that we fixed in 10.2. It should only be happening on tools that lock the data in the ToC, which in your case, Snap would because it is making edits to the data.

Comment: I do have background geoprocessing enabled. I'm not sure if having that enabled automatically means it is processing in the background or not. We purchased 10.2 Monday so there should not be an issue anymore. Thanks

Comment: @KHibma you should add that as an answer, since it seems to have been confirmed.